# Getting "simple" remote objects in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

When I call a remote function in electron, the results are always littered with `getters` and `setters`. I think I understand why this is, but I'd like to be able to get simple objects.

[image: setters/getters]

#### My current solution is this:

```
import {remote} from 'electron'

const bridge = remote.require('bridge')  // This is a little script I create for talking to a python process. Over stdin/stdout i.e. pipes.

bridge.on('fileTreeUpdate', (data) => {
    myDataStore.update(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.tree))
})
```

#### Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to require 'bridge' via remote? Typically, you can require any module directly in the Renderer process; you only need the remote module if you want to access an Electron module that is only available in the main process or a particular instance of a module already loaded by the main process. Unless you are loading 'bridge' in the main process in order to load it just once and then have multiple windows access it, you can probably just require it directly in the renderer and therefore won't have to deal with remote objects at all.

Comment: I have a python process running, using `child_process.spawn`. It should be available in both the `renderer` and the main process.

Comment: I see. Do you need to access the same python process from both Main and Renderer? Or do you need to only access it from the Renderer anyway? In the latter case, just use 'bridge' directly as there's no need to go via remote. Otherwise you will have to resort to some sort of IPC; in fact, Electron's `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` would probably make for a better solution than using `remote`.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what I ended up with. But I'm still curious if there is a better solution to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I would suggest to require 'bridge' directly in the Renderer; this way you don't need to pass its data between the Main and Renderer processes at all.

Having said that, if another requirement made it necessary to load the 'bridge' module in the Main process only, while still accessing its data from the Renderer, I'd suggest to use Electron's 'ipc' modules.

For instance, in your main process you could do something like this (assuming the variable `win` is a reference to the window of the Renderer process you wish to communicate with):

```
import bridge from 'bridge'

bridge.on('fileTreeUpdate', data => {
  // assuming win {BrowserWindow} has already been initialized
  win.webContents.send('bridge:fileTreeUpdate', data) 
})
```

And in your Renderer processes (associated with `win`):

```
import ipcRenderer from 'electron'

ipcRenderer.on('bridge:fileTreeUpdate', (event, data) => {
  myDataStore.update(data.tree)
})
```